# Movie or TV show involving a menacing ventriloquist's dummy

Tags: story-identification

I remember watching a show on TV (pretty sure it was a movie) in black and white (although could have been shot in color, just viewed on a B&W set) in which a ventriloquist's dummy seemed to become sentient with murderous intent.

It is not "The Twilight Zone": The Dummy (1962), but may have been of similar vintage.

If I recall correctly, the story combined elements of suspense and intrigue/whodunnit amongst a group of characters (not just interplay of ventriloquist and dummy as in the 'Zone episode I mentioned), and I think the ending left some ambiguity as to "who done it" and whether the dummy was truly alive within the context of the story or just in the mind of one or more characters.

Can anyone help me identify the movie or TV show?

Comment: http://io9.com/the-10-creepiest-ventriloquist-dummies-of-all-time-458555695

Comment: Man... there's a lot of them. Check the ones at http://www.toplessrobot.com/2010/04/the_10_creepiest_ventriloquist_tales_of_all_time.php and see if any of them match up.

Comment: Note that the dummy from "Twilight Zone: The Dummy" was actually re-used in another episode.

Comment: For the record, I'm tempted to close as *too broad*. This description fits at least 4 off my list and 3 more off of @SeanDuggan's

Comment: @SeanDuggan Thanks for the link. I think it was "Dead of Night" (1945). Found a YouTube clip containing excerpts which seem to fit with my memory.

Comment: Uncanny valley, baby

Answer (score 5, accepted):

["Dead of Night" (1945)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0037635). A group of people are gathered together, each tells a tale. Among them, a story of a ventriloquist and his dummy.

Comment: So how did you find it?

Answer (score 5):

Could you be referring to the movie "Magic" based on William Goldman's book by the same name?  Book published in 1976, the movie starred a young Anthony Hopkins.

Answer (score 1):

It might be a book (or tv episode) in the Goosebumps series, specifically from the [Night of the Living Dummy](http://goosebumps.wikia.com/wiki/Night_of_the_Living_Dummy) storyline.

[image]

> Plot from back cover:
>
> HE'S NO DUMMY!
>
> Lindy names the ventriloquist's dummy she finds Slappy. Slappy is kind of ugly, but he's a lot of fun. Lindy's having a great time learning to make Slappy move and talk. But Kris is jealous of all the attention her sister is getting. It's no fair. Why does Lindy have all the luck? Kris decides to get a dummy of her own. She'll show Lindy. Then weird things begin to happen. Nasty things. Evil things. No way a dummy can be causing all the trouble. Or is there?

You can check out the Night of the Living Dummy episode from the Goosebumps TV show [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q3Nek4W4Uiw).